# How do avoid showing only "..." when stringing a block of text

Tags: php, string, text

My aim is to string an amount of text if larger than 85 characters and only display 85 characters followed by "...".

However, in some cases it only shows "..." and no text at all. Is there a reason for this? i.e. is this caused by certain characters? (i.e. ; " etc)?

If so, your guidance would be highly appreciated

My code is:

```
if ((strlen($row["description"]) > 85) && (strlen($row["description"]) > 1)) {
    $whitespaceposition = strpos($row["description"]," ",85);
    $description_string = substr($row["description"],0,$whitespaceposition)."...";
}
else if ((strlen($row["description"]) < 85) && (strlen($row["description"]) > 1)) {
    $description_string = $row["description"];
}
```

Thank you all in advance

George

Comment: last time I check anything bigger than 85 MUST SURELY BE bigger than 1, so your first if statement doesn't need the second condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the length of the description is exactly 85 then it probably won't display anything.

It may be more reliable to show the whole description, but use these CSS rules to take care of trimming them:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Then the browser takes care of ensuring the text is trimmed and adds `...` to the end for you.

Comment: +1 for typing exactly what I was gonna suggest as second alternative :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) should i asign a width to the area also to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my function to solve this:

```
function shortern($str, $int_length = 30) {

    if (strlen($str) <= $int_length)
        return $str;
    else {

        $str    =   substr($str, 0, ($int_length - 3));

        return preg_replace("/^(.*)[\s\.]+[^\s\.]*$/", "$1...", $str);

    }

}
```

Basicly I run a regexp to find first fully free word and add the dots to that, so it rather appends dots to `hello...` instead of `hello ther...` (hello there)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to all the good answers up there

```
$desc = $row["description"];
return substr($desc, 0, 85) . (strlen($desc) > 85 ? '...' : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strlen($row["description"]) > 85) {
    $whitespaceposition = strpos($row["description"]," ",85);
    $description_string = substr($row["description"],0,$whitespaceposition)."...";
}
else {
    $description_string = $row["description"];
}
```